# Binary operators - Add More Than 2 Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If I have the sum of *3 or more numbers*, e.g., 1 + 2 + 3 + 50, will the sum end up being done **in pairs**, i.e., the + operator is binary and thus only supports 2 operands at a time?

I am new to algebra, I'm talking about basic arithmetic, the basic addition that we all know.

Comment: Yes, that is formally the case.  The abuse of notation (omitting the parentheses that tell you what order to go in) is possible because addition is associative, so that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, we apply the binary operation to 2 objects and then take the output and apply it to the third.  If the operator is associative, we have flexability in which pair to operate upon first.  If not, we need some process to understand the order of operations.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This is why we need special machinery to handle infinite sums

Comment: Excellent @Robert Shore, the same applies to the multiplication operator, i.e., the multiplication operator itself is also a **binary operator**, right?

Comment: Hi @user317176, could you give me other common examples of associative operators?

Comment: Yes, multiplication and function composition are also associative; see more examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the addition operator is purely binary. However, because it is associative (meaning that $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$) and commutative (meaning that $a + b = b + a$), it doesn't matter what order you perform the additions in and so $a + b + c$ has n unambiguous value, hence we omit the parentheses in typical notation.

This becomes important when you introduce other operators that don't have the same properties - or we work in a different system where $+$ behaves differently - and we need to establish a clear order of operations.

Comment: "*it doesn't matter what order you perform the additions in and so a+b+c has n unambiguous value, hence we omit the parentheses in typical notation.*" - Does "n unambiguous value" mean that the result does not change regardless of the order? @ConMan

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean - you can calculate $a + b$ and then add $c$, or you can calculate $c + a$ and add $b$, or any other combination.

Comment: Are the subtraction (-), division (/) and multiplication (x) operators also binary operators but **only** addition and multiplication in turn are associative? @ConMan

Comment: That's right. So an expression like $4 - 3 - 1$ is ambiguous, and we have rules about the order of operations to determine what it means (and the rule is that you perform the subtractions left-to-right, so it's implicitly $(4-3)-1 = 0$.

Comment: Excellent @ConMan, now it's a little clearer, marked as best answer